# Issue sorting tuples in python3

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.4

Below is my code and i am trying to sort the tuple with respect to 2nd element.

```
list = ["abc14_90","abc44_88","abc14_89"]
listLength = len(list)
for i in range(0,listLength):
    tempList = list[i].split('_')
    tempList1 = tempList[0].split('c')
    if(i==0):
        tupleNumber = [(list[i], int(tempList1[1]),int(tempList[1]))]
    else:
        tupleNumber = tupleNumber + [(list[i], int(tempList1[1]),int(tempList[1]))]

print (tupleNumber)

sorted(tupleNumber, key=lambda x: x[2])

print (tupleNumber)
```

Expected Output:

```
[ ('abc44_88', 44, 88), ('abc14_89', 14, 89),('abc14_90', 14, 90),]
```

Output Observed:

```
[('abc14_90', 14, 90), ('abc44_88', 44, 88), ('abc14_89', 14, 89)]
```

Basically the sort seems to have no effect.

Comment: Why not just `list_.sort(key=lambda x: re.search('(\d+)$', x).group(1)) `

Answer (score 0):

`sorted()` doesn't sort in place but it returns a sorted list, so you need to reassign the list to `tupleNumber` as the following:

```
print (tupleNumber)

tupleNumber = sorted(tupleNumber, key=lambda x: x[2])

print (tupleNumber)
```

Comment: I think he meant second element from the initial value which is the third element in the tuple ie: `abc44_88` -> `('abc44_88', 44, 88)`

Comment: might also want to point out the `.sort()` method of lists

Comment: @MoeA Hmm, I guess so. Perhaps OP should clarify.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it sorts in place. Also, i meant second element from initial value.

Comment: @mooonimoon as @AnthonySottile mentioned, you can use `tupleNumber.sort()` which will sort in place

Comment: Thanks @AnthonySottile and MoeA will look into that method.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import re
import itertools
l = ["abc14_90","abc44_88","abc14_89"]
new_l = [tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[i], map(int, re.findall("\d+", i))])) for i in sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x[-2:]))]
```

Output:

```
[('abc44_88', 44, 88), ('abc14_89', 14, 89), ('abc14_90', 14, 90)]
```